# Is it possible to call PHP in html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a PHP that returns some HTML code, for example, if I execute this in the browser,

http://www.myserver.com/myscript.php?size=300

this will return some html code like this,

```
'<div><a href="..."><img src="..." /></a></div>'
```

I am wondering if it's possible I can call this php script in my html code directly? For example, if I want to use the output from the PHP script in my Wordpress sidebar widget?

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: Wordpress is just php, so yea you can do that. You can affect the sidebar.php file directly or you can write your own custom plugin to deliver the results of your script to the sidebar markup. If your file is remote, you can look into something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php
        $html = file_get_contents("http://www.myserver.com/myscript.php?size=300");
        echo $html;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2864740 - wordpress is written in php. the html for sidebar would accept what marty suggested

Answer (score 1):

If your Current page's extension is not php, you cannot call php in it directly.
You have to use some `javascript/jquery/ajax` to run the php file externally and load the data into a class or id using one of those javascript based code.
If your current page is already a php file than,you can use `include();` or `require();` functions and it does the job.

Comment: You could also use an iframe if you're not comfortable with JavaScript and AJAX, though that is a very messy approach.

Comment: @MartyWallace i agree.

Answer (score 0):

above answers are correct, but that might be not concerned for wordpress, that are of core php functionality.

i have a different way for sidebar use, that's provide by wordpress already.

it is an inbuilt functionality, please take a look towards my answer.

[Show active sidebar in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374149/show-active-sidebar-in-wordpress/19374677#19374677)

[How to make wordpress sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148894/how-to-make-wordpress-sidebar/19151369#19151369)

you can found ::

try this one, it is different way of using sidebar

[1] put your all "left_bar"(sidebar) code in a new file named "sidebar-left_bar"

[2] save it with header.php, function.php and all files (saving location)

[3] now just use `<?php get_sidebar( 'left_bar' ); ?>` where you want to use

Thanks